# gradle dependency management default of using newest artifact

Tags: gradle

I read in the gradle docs that

```
"Newest - used by default by Gradle - the newest version of the dependency is used. 
This strategy has been in Gradle since early days."
```

yet, I when I use code to copy configuration, I see duplicate jars with different versions

```
task('copyJars') { 
    //ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    //delete ext.collection
    copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
    //copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
}
```

Here is one of them..

```
snakeyaml-1.6.jar
snakeyaml-1.7.jar
```

This is the latest 1.1 gradle download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conflict resolution only occurs for dependencies from Maven or Ivy repositories which have the necessary metadata (pom.xml or ivy.xml).

Answer (score 0):

IT seems this one is not supported when using the "newest" version of jars ...

```
compile fileTree(dir: project.ext.fixedLibDir, include: '*.jar')
```

so you have to manually do it yourself :(.